# Makefile: Set environment variable for future use as part of a build step

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to set an environment variable as part of a build step that is then consumed by a subsequent build step?

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. One build steps logs into a secrets server and obtains login credentials for the specific build target it's been asked to build.
2. A later build step uses those credentials to deploy to a specific targeted environment.

Is there a way to export an environment variable from step 1 that would then be available in step 2?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.  It's a fundamental aspect of processes in all POSIX systems that one process cannot modify the environment of its parent (or siblings).  So when a process (regardless of how it's invoked) obtains those values it cannot "promote" them up into the environment of its parent.

The process could write them to a file that a later process can read.

Alternatively, the process could print them out and the parent process could capture the output and remember it, and parse it into its own environment.  In GNU make that could be something like:

```
creds := $(shell get-my-credentials)
```

Without more details of the requirements and restrictions it's hard to be precise.